# App is reopening all time from the splash screen

Tags: android, performance

I have an issue in my app only for the specific device only when I am clicking on the home button after performing the few steps in my app, soo app is in the recent tabs.
If I will open the app from the recent tabs then it will open from the last page where I drop the app last, but if I will click on the app icon instead of recent tabs then the app will open from the splash screen.

This will happen only for the one Samsung device and other apps were working fine for the same device.

Please do help me if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: Please share your manifest file. This is related to `launchMode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Manifest file is what determines the "launcher" or what activity will start when opening your app from the icon. While browsing through the app, if you open another application or press the home button your app goes into the foreground or "pause" state. That is why when you find your app in the recent tab it is resumed from it's last location. The question is where exactly do you want your app to start from?
Your android manifest file should be the only file with an orange icon in your project file list. Open it up and it should look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bnr.que_snitch">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".CrimeListActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CrimeListActivity">

                  //THIS IS YOUR LAUNCHER!!!

            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In order copy and paste your launcher (everything inside the intent filter tag)and paste it inside of the activity tag that you want your application to start from.

Comment: those are criminal activities :)

Comment: hehe. This book was where it all started for me!

Answer (score 4):

I did face the same issue in the past and that too with a Samsung device.

The solution(may be temporary fix for you as I did not test it on other models of Samsung) which worked in my case is to write below code in the onCreate() of the initial/launch Activity:

```
    if (!isTaskRoot()
            && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            && getIntent().getAction() != null
            && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

        finish();
        return;
    }
```